# Broken symlink to dual booted windows until I open that part of the file system from the gui

Tags: ubuntu, symlink

I dual boot windows and ubuntu. On windows, I have a folder, "Books", that contains all the books I may or may not have taken from library genesis. It would be inconvenient and inefficent to duplicate this directory, so I created a symbolic link. The symlink is broken (I.E ls displays it in red) until I click on the SSD icon labeled "OS" on the Ubuntu sidebar, after which nautilus opens to my root windows directory and the symlink works once more.
So apparently simply following a symlink doesn't initiate the process of loading the windows partition. Is there a way to change this? What would you recommend I do in this situation? I realize I'm very ignorant about this subject, so I'm also researching it now.

Comment: Sounds like you're windows drive just isn't mounted at the point where you want to access it, and opening your file manager does that. You could make that might happen every boot automatically.

Comment: Crafting mounts for Windows (NTFS) partitions is something of an art form, because file permissions are handled so differently. Basically, the whole Windows partition is owned by the Linux user who mounted it most recently. My mount reports as this (I'm not proud of it): `/dev/sda2 on /media/root/Windows type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096) [Windows]`